# Is there any way to "flush" interned strings?

Tags: java, string, memory-management, string-interning

I'm using an external library which uses String.intern() for performance reasons. That's fine, but I'm invoking that library *a lot* in a given run and so I run into the dreaded

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Obviously I can use the JVM command-line `-XX:MaxPermSize` modifier, but that solution isn't very scalable. Instead, is there any way to periodically (between two "batches" of library calls) "flush" the interned string pool, i.e. empty the static table of strings held by the String class?

Comment: I guess definition of "fine" needs to be re-evaluated :p

Comment: @pst yea :) what I mean is that these strings are interned for a good reason, good enough that I don't want to "flush" that table after every invocation, or prevent interning completely - I just want to flush it after every "batch" of invocations, so that inside each batch the library still gets to enjoy the interning from previous calls.

Comment: Strange - just read an [article](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/01/busting-javalangstringintern-myths.html) saying, that modern JVM will gc interned Strings. Maybe you're keeping to many references to unused String objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Just size permgen appropriately. It's no different to having to size the heap appropriately. Don't be afraid!

Answer (score 3):

Investigating further, I found [this article](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/01/busting-javalangstringintern-myths.html), which seems to demonstrate that interned strings are still garbage collected. I guess that means that my problem here is a deeper one - the library I use must still hold a living reference to these strings :(

Comment: Can't you just.. kinda kill all your refs to the library and 'start over' every batch. If I read that correctly the GC should kick in for the 'old' interned strings, and you might be happy?

Comment: @Nanne that library uses static variables liberally (shudder). It has a nice little `reset()` function for them, which I relied upon, but I guess it is incomplete.

Comment: bummer ;) interesting article nevertheless ;)